# can only write to buffer byte by byte, buf.write() says argument must be string... but it is Node

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use the Buffer module in Node to convert between encoding types. It works for my purposes when I write the string to the buffer byte by byte, but buf.write() says argument must be a string, even though I am passing it a string.

This works:

```
  var buf = new Buffer(this.length)
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    buf[i] = this.charCodeAt(i)
  }
  return buf.toString('base64')
```

This doesn't:

```
// Inside String.prototype.base64()
var buf = new Buffer(this.length)
buf.write(this, 0, this.length, 'base64')
```

Comment: Tip: you should generally avoid mutating built-in objects' prototypes and such.

Comment: codewars kata. that's the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing string OBJECT to the buffer, not a simple string. So to solve it try:

```
var buf = new Buffer(this.length)
buf.write(this.toString(), 0, this.length, 'base64')
```

Comment: i don't normally mutate built in objects, this is just the set up for this problem on codewars.

Comment: @user137717 ok. I'll remove my PS then.